# DHCP in IPv6, Option 82

Tags: ipv6, dhcp

I am going to develop DHCP IPv6 client configuration in my application.
I want to few details about DHCP Options in IPv6.
1.Likewise in DHCP v4 ,dont we have Option 82 in v6. If not, what is replacement for Option 82

2.I am using Cable Modem and CPE environment
 In my CPE and CM initialization for IPv4 i am using following configuration for sending DISCOVER message to Server

```
DHCPMessage messageOut = new DHCPMessage();
        // fill DHCPMessage object 
        messageOut.setOp((byte) 1); 
        messageOut.setHtype((byte) 1);
        messageOut.setHlen((byte) 6);
        messageOut.setHops((byte) 0);
        messageOut.setXid(myXid); // should be a random int
        messageOut.setSecs((short) 0);
        messageOut.setFlags((short) 0);
        byte[] mac = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(myMac,0,mac,0,6);
        messageOut.setChaddr(mac); // set globaly defined hwaddr
        byte[] op82data = DHCPUtils.buildOption82WithUserData(myCMmac, myOption82UserData, myOption82Field9Val);
        messageOut.setOption(82, op82data); // cm mac must be imcluded in discover.
        byte[] op67data = DHCPUtils.getOption67(myOption67UserData);
        messageOut.setOption(67, op67data);
        messageOut.setFile(DHCPUtils.getOption67BootFile(op67data));
        byte[] opt = new byte[1];
        opt[0] = (byte) DHCPMessage.DISCOVER;
        messageOut.setOption(53, opt);
        myState = GET_OFFER_AND_SEND_REQUEST;
        return sendDHCPMessage(messageOut)
```

Wanted to know how can i achieve this in IPv6 for SOLICIT message.

I am not able to understand the DOCSIS 3.0 specification ,since i am new to this .
Any help would be appreciable. Need some urgently.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your comments on this..It is much need for me.

Answer (score 1):

DHCP option 81 is Relay Agent information, refer to http://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xml and 
rfc3046

Relay Agent Remote-ID Option 37 is the DHCPv6 equivalent, specified in RFC 4649.

I don't have any information about using RFC 4649 together with DOCSIS, but I hope the above helps.